# How to trigger an event in angular app for unit testing?

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I am running unit test in angular, I want to trigger a click event, this is a drop down upon clicking it drops down a list of Customer numbers. I want to trigger this event in my unit test, if this event is successfully triggered, I can update the customer info corresponding to index of clicked button. I have attached necessary code for reference. Please let me know how to trigger click event?

```
//template.html 
<mat-menu #menuFilter="matMenu">
    <button *ngFor="let customer of customers; let i = index" (click)="onCustomerChange(i)" mat-menu-item class="selectCustomerData">{{customer.licenseownerid}}</button>
 </mat-menu>
```

```
//angular generated code
<div class="mat-menu-panel ng-trigger ng-trigger-transformMenu ng-tns-c10-1 mat-menu-after
 mat-menu-below ng-star-inserted mat-elevation-z2" role="menu" tabindex="-1" ng-reflect-klass="mat-menu-panel" 
 ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]" style="transform-origin: left top;">
    <div class="mat-menu-content">
          <button class="selectCustomerData mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted" mat-menu-item="" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">0LPT_id0306
            <div class="mat-menu-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]">
            </div>
          </button>
          <button class="selectCustomerData mat-menu-item ng-star-inserted" mat-menu-item="" role="menuitem" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">0LPT_id03061
           <div class="mat-menu-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]">
           </div>
          </button>
       </div>
...and so on
</div>
```

```
//component.ts
 onCustomerChange(i) {
    this.customerNumber = this.customers[i].licenseownerid;
    this.customerName = this.customers[i].licenseownername;
}
```

Comment: I‘m still a bit unsure about what exactly you‘d like to test. Are you trying to trigger the first button to then have the other buttons visible so you can click one of them or is it enough to test your own button‘s click method since the other click mechanism is a material component which is probably already tested?

Comment: I am trying to trigger the first button to make other buttons visible, so I can click on one these buttons. Upon clicking one of these buttons.The index of clicked button is button is passed to onChangeCustomer(index). I want to spy on this method if it is called or not also if it called with correct index or not

Comment: Is there a possibility to test the template that is without angular compiled one???

Comment: What do you mean with ‚without angular compiled one‘? If you want to test the whole process including the material components you would need to mock the directive matMenuTriggerFor which seems to be responsible for showing the buttons you want to test as far as I can see from your examples. The question is whether it‘s actually worth the effort, since the material components itself are probably well tested. Wouldn‘t it be enough to test your own buttons. Therefore it would be sufficient to stub the customers and click the button for a customer and expect the new customer id and customer name

Comment: Could you maybe create a stackblitz with a minimal working example showing the customers and the menu selection button and the customer button and your onCustomerChange method? I‘ll have a look at the test afterwards.

Comment: Well thats correct, I needn't mock the entire directive  but please let me know how to do it the way you have suggested

Comment: ok I create  a stackblitz

Comment: Hi  Erbsenkoenig, here is the url https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umrcpz, I want to test if the onCustomerChange is getting called with right index or not

Comment: let spycustomer=spyOn(component,'onCustomerChange');
 component.customers=mockActivatedElasticUnits;//mock for customers
 let button=document.createElement('button');
  button.setAttribute('id','0');
      let id= button.getAttribute('id');
      let createTextNode=document.createTextNode(component.customers[0]);
      button.appendChild(createTextNode);
       button.onclick= mockService.onCustomerChange(id);

       expect(spycustomer).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: But the test fails, let me know if the click event is correctly added and Am I correctly triggering the event

Comment: Am I right in assuming your customer array is not empty in your working version but populated with some sort of data?

Comment: I am able to print the array and see values

Comment: That's how I would test that component https://stackblitz.com/edit/testing-mat-menu

Comment: button.addEventListener('click',function(){component.onCustomerChange(id);});

Comment: This passed the test, thanks Erbsenkoenig

Comment: why would you want to add the event listener to the button in your test? the test works without that. did you check out my stackblitz?

Comment: I tried removing the click event the test doesn't pass, as intention of the test is to ensure a method is called on click event

Comment: But the click event is triggered in my example? Have you checked the stackblitz? See line 48. `buttonDebugElems[2].triggerEventHandler('click', null);` This line triggers the click event on the button of the second customer!

Answer (score 0):

Since event number one is an angular material event, I would probably assume that triggering the mat-menu on click works and would not include this particular event within the test case.

I would rather use a NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA in the test setup and only trigger the click events of your own buttons:

The spec.ts would look something like this:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-menu',
  exportAs: 'matMenu'
})
class DirectiveStub {
}

describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent, DirectiveStub],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('click on second button', fakeAsync(() => {
      component.customers = [
        {licenseownerid: 'ID_1', licenseownername: 'NAME_1'},
        {licenseownerid: 'ID_2', licenseownername: 'NAME_2'}
        ]
      fixture.detectChanges();

      const buttonDebugElems: DebugElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));

      expect(buttonDebugElems.length).toEqual(3);

      buttonDebugElems[2].triggerEventHandler('click', null);
      tick();

      expect(component.customerName).toEqual('NAME_2');
      expect(component.customerNumber).toEqual('ID_2');
    }));
});
```

**Important to note**

Unfortunately it is necessary to stub the directive angular material uses for it's menu. That's the empty (not exported) directive at the top of the spec file. If you have more components with that menu you would like to test, it might be an idea to move that directive into a single file placed inside a separate folder, e.g. 'test', so you can reuse that directive within your tests, but is not bundled into your application.

Here is a working example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/testing-mat-menu)